# Where is Ubuntu installed when I create a dual-boot setup?

Tags: windows, partitioning, dual-boot

I am an Ubuntu newbie. I have just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. I am dual-booting. But what I wonder is where did Ubuntu get installed to, and how much partition space is Ubuntu using right now? For example, I didn't setup partitions for `/`, `/home`, etc. Setup completed the installation without notifying me anything.

Comment: Where Ubuntu is installed depends on how you installed it. Did you use Wubi in Windows, or boot the LiveCD?

Comment: Also, your question about Google Chrome would be better as a separate post, as we try to keep to one issue per post here. (As a quick answer, it saves by default to your `~/Downloads` folder, though you can change this behavior in Chrome if you want.)

Comment: I have installed it with usb disk

Comment: Okay, but did you boot your system from the USB, or did you plug it in while running Windows and open Wubi?

Comment: no i didnt use wubi. i did boot it from usb. and now i looked; filesystem partition there is 15gb free space.

Comment: Open the terminal and run `lsblk`, `mount`, `df` or `sudo fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start a new thread for each of your questions.
Let me give you a basic understanding of partitions in Ubuntu or generally every other Linux distro.
In a Linux system everything is file including all your hard drive partitions, your optical drives and every other I/O device. All those files are located inside a space called "root".
Basically if you see it from a "Windows Viewpoint", that root partition is where your Ubuntu is installed. It usually is of ext4 file system and can not be seen from windows by usual means.
You can use a partition manager like gParted to review your partition table.

Comment: Ok there is a "File System" in file browser which has all the Ubuntu stuff on it. But how can i know how much disk space has this partition own and for example if i want to expand the size of it, is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the partition you have mounted as root. In nautilus (file manager) you can see the free space of root partition when you are in your home. As I mentioned you can get much more information from `gParted`. For installing it type `sudo apt-get install gparted` in a terminal.